# I'm trying to loop on bootstrap tabs with ngFor,

Tags: html, jquery, angular

I'm trying to loop on bootstrap tabs with ngFor, And it shows up all tabs because active class is also looped, How Can I show only First tab by default
however, nav-tabs is working correctly.
What I need is:
loop tab-pane with the active class for every active nav-link

**HTML**

```
<section id="new-recipes">
  <div class="recipes-title">
    <h1>NEW RECIPES</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="recipe-tabs">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div
          class="nav flex-column nav-pills"
          id="v-pills-tab"
          role="tablist"
          aria-orientation="vertical"
        >
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            *ngFor="let tab of sections.recipes"
            id="v-pills-home-tab"
            data-toggle="pill"
            href="#v-pills-{{ tab.id }}"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="v-pills-home"
            aria-selected="true"
            >{{ tab.category.title }}
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipe-body">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div
          class="tab-content h-100"
          id="v-pills-tabContent"
          *ngFor="let recipe of sections.recipes"
        >
          <div
            class="tab-pane h-100 fade show active"
            id="v-pills-{{ recipe.id }}"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
          >
            <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="recipe-description">
                  <h4>{{ recipe?.title }}</h4>
                  <p
                    class="text-white e2e-inner-html-bound"
                    [innerHTML]="recipe.description"
                  ></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please create a stackblitz link

Answer (score 1):

In an `*ngFor` loop you have access to several variables like odd, even, last, first and index, whereas you *could* reference the value of `first` in order to add the `active` class to the first div only, as you asked, using the `ngClass` directive on the `div` or pill, like so:

```
<div class="tab-content h-100"
     id="v-pills-tabContent"
     *ngFor="let recipe of sections.recipes; let first = first;">
          <div id="v-pills-{{ recipe.id }}"
               role="tabpanel"
               aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
               class="tab-pane h-100 fade show"
               [ngClass]="{'active': first}">
```

*However,* if the intended implementation is to have a set of pills that a user can toggle through, then setting the `active` class by targeting the `first` element in that way would not be practical since the first pill would always retain the `active` class even if the user selects another one.

If you would prefer instead that the `active` class dynamically change, based on user selection, you could do the following as an alternative implementation:

First, create a property in your component intended to track the active `index` based on the users selection, and initialize that property with the value of the first `index` in your `*ngFor` loop as `0` like so:

```
public activePillIndex:number = 0;
```

Then, write a function in the component designed to change the value of `activePillIndex` to match the `index` of the pill a user selects like so:

```
public selectPill(index:number) {
 this.activePillIndex = index;
 // do some other stuff if necessary...
}
```

And lastly, in your template:

Reference the `index` to determine whether or not it matches the selected pill, which will be stored in the `activePillIndex` property, in order for `[ngClass]` to add the `active` class accordingly.

And use the `(click)` event to call the `selectPill()` function designed to track the `index` of subsequently selected pills like so:

```
<div class="tab-content h-100"
         id="v-pills-tabContent"
         *ngFor="let recipe of sections.recipes; let index = index;">
              <div id="v-pills-{{ recipe.id }}"
                   role="tabpanel"
                   aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
                   class="tab-pane h-100 fade show"
                   [ngClass]="{'active': index === activePillIndex}"
                   (click)="selectPill(index)">
```

Given that the value of `index` for the first element in your `*ngFor` loop will be `0`, `[ngClass]` will apply the `active` class to the first element when the component is instantiated and subsequent `click` events will cause the `[ngClass]` directive to set the `active` class to the selected pill and remove the `active` class from the previously selected pill accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar and I have been able to come up with this solution, I hope someone will help you

```
<section id="new-recipes">
    <div class="recipes-title">
        <h1>NEW RECIPES</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-tabs">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-link" *ngFor="let tab of HEROES; let index = index;" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill"
                        href="#v-pills-{{ tab.id }}" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true"
                        [ngClass]="{'active': index === activePillIndex}"
                        (click)="selectPill(index)">
                        {{tab.name }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-body">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="tab-content h-100" id="v-pills-tabContent" *ngFor="let recipe of HEROES; let index = index;">
                    <div class="tab-pane h-100 fade show active" id="v-pills-{{ recipe.id }}" role="tabpanel"
                        aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                        <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="recipe-description" *ngIf="activePillIndex === index">
                                    <h4>{{ recipe?.id }}</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

ts

```
HEROES = [
    { id: 1, name: "Superman" },
    { id: 2, name: "Batman" },
    { id: 5, name: "BatGirl" },
    { id: 3, name: "Robin" },
    { id: 4, name: "Flash" }
  ];

public activePillIndex:number = 0;



public selectPill(index:number) {
    this.activePillIndex = index;
}
```